# How to display or print all elements of a large python list in the editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, atom-editor

I have a pandas dataframe with 423 variables.

I would like to display (print)  all of the column (variable) names in the editor so that I can check the exact names for variables.  I am using ATOM IDE.

To do this, I first use `df.columns`.  This displays a handful of column names followed by '...'

I have tried to change the pandas display properties as follows:

```
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 999)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 999)
```

But this does not seem to change the number of elements displayed, presumably because this is a list not a DataFrame.

I have worked around this by creating a DataFrame instead of relying on a list as follows:

```
cNames = pd.DataFrame({'columnNames':df.columns})
```

But I think it would be useful to know how to change the number of elements of a list that are displayed for future work.

Can this be done?

Comment: `for x in df.columns: print(x)` Just print one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just print one by one:

```
for x in df.columns:
    print(x)
```

Does that help?

Comment: This does achieve that I want to achieve, but in a slightly different way.  I will still with this solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may **also** wish to set `display.width` to a large number.

Comment: Thanks.  This does change the width of the window displaying the elements, but not the number of elements.  I still get the '...' in the middle of the list and only a subset of elements are displayed.